# Draper gem not decorating associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm following the Draper gem documentation, but the associated model is not being decorated. Here's a snippet of my top-level decorator:

```
module Admin
  class OrderDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    delegate_all
    decorates_finders
    decorates_association :line_item

    def amount
      model.amount.nil? ? 0 : model.amount
    end
  end
end
```

And here's a snippet from my association decorator:

```
module Admin
  class LineItemDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    delegate_all

    def options
      model.options.present? ? model.options.to_s : 'N/A'
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the method in the controller that calls the decorator:

```
  def show
    @subject = Admin::OrderDecorator.find(params[:id])
  end
```

It's being used in the view like so:

```
@subject.line_items.each do |li|
  = li.options
```

...etc...

The options method on LineItemDecorator is just being ignored - if it's nil, it doesn't display anything, rather than 'N/A'. I've put binding.pry in the options method and it never gets called. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Sure @xeon131! These are trimmed down versions -

`module Admin`
  `class Order < ActiveRecord::Base`
    `has_many :line_items`
  `end`
`end`

`module Admin`

  `class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base`

    `belongs_to :order`

  `end`

`end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use plural `line_items` not singular `line_item` to make it work because that is how your association is named.

```
 decorates_association :line_items
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, but I think I was getting another error that was unrelated. At any rate, I've changed it per your recommendation and it is working now. Thank you!